# AWS beanstalk Amazon Linux 2 log file permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch, rsyslog

I'm migrated from AL1 to AL2 on AWS Beanstalk. AL2 changed location of my nodejs.log to `/var/log/{{.}}.stdout.log`
I resolved this by adding ryslog.config to .ebexetensions:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/rsyslog.conf.template":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      # This rsyslog file redirects Elastic Beanstalk platform logs.
      # Logs are initially sent to syslog, but we also want to divide
      # stdout and stderr into separate log files.

      template(name="SimpleFormat" type="string" string="%msg%\n")
      $EscapeControlCharactersOnReceive off

      {{range .ProcessNames}}if $programname  == '{{.}}' then {
        *.=warning;*.=err;*.=crit;*.=alert;*.=emerg /var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log; SimpleFormat
        *.=info;*.=notice /var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log; SimpleFormat
      }
      {{end}}
```

Above configuration is working but I have problem with log file permissions.
Directory /var/log/nodejs and nodejs.log file are only readable by root (chmod 600), and cloudwatch-agent can't read it. Changing permissions manually do the job, but how can I change the permissions to be created automatically on beanstalk deploy?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @Leandro, yes Answer below

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following code resolved it.
This will set the `owner` and `group` to the corresponding value, for all files that are automatically created.

```
# Set the default permissions for all log files
$umask 0022
$FileOwner cwagent
$FileGroup cwagent
$DirOwner cwagent
$DirGroup cwagent
```